# Relationship metric space and $\sigma$-discrete base

Tags: metric-spaces

Hy, I am newbie here. Can you help me to prove this proposition?

> If $X$ metric space, then there is a $\sigma$-discrete base
>   $\mathcal{U}$ for the topology of $X$, i.e.,
>   $\mathcal{U}=\bigcup\{\mathcal{U}_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where each
>   $\mathcal{U}_{n}$ is a discrete family af non-empty open subsets of
>   $X$.

A family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is said to be discrete if each $x\in X$ has a neighborhood in $X$ that intersect at most one member of $\mathcal{A}$.

Thank you.

Comment: This is half of the [Bing metrization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_metrization_theorem). Its proof is fairly non-trivial unless you’ve already proved some fairly high-powered results about metric spaces. Do you know, for instance, that metric spaces are paracompact?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Wikipedia article given by Brian M. Scott does not have the proof, and somebody might find this question using a search engine as I just did, I'll give a reference from a text book as an answer.

You can find a proof of this in *General Topology* by Ryszard Engelking. The statement appears as Theorem 4.4.3 on p. 281, although the work is done using Theorem 4.4.1, that every open cover of a metrizable space has a $\sigma$-discrete open refinement.